# PureCSS.io - Pure Grid (height) displays different in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, yui-pure-css

I am using the Pure Grids of PureCSS. I have a `pure-g` with three `pure-u-1-3`, containing a few paragraphs. The problem is that there is a difference in display between Chrome/IE and Firefox when one of the units is longer than the others.

http://jsfiddle.net/f3YNe/3/

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFVYu.png

I have tried to use jQuery to calculate the highest `pure-u-1-3` and setting the rest to this height. But it didn't work out as expected, since this grid has to be responsive as well (using `pure-g-r`)

Does anybody know how to make Firefox produce the same output?

Comment: It's a good question. You have a minimal fiddle that does demonstrate the problem, so we couldn't ask for more. Only one thing: what did you try, which tools did you use to try and pinpoint the problem?

Comment: @MrLister I used jQuery to solve this problem, [see this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f3YNe/6/). But my page has to be responsive as well. I could use `$(window).on('resize')`, but i'd rather use a nicer solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As purecss has [fixed the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20825170/purecss-io-pure-grid-height-displays-different-in-firefox/21186648#answer-25546647) (v0.6) by implementing it in every browser, this answer is obsolete.

## Previous answer:

Your problem is that PureCSS is using `-ms-display: flex` in Internet Explorer and `-webkit-display: flex` in Webkit Browsers. Opera, Firefox and (obviously) older IEs don't get this solution.

To get it working in Firefox (20+) and Opera you could apply the following in your stylesheet:

```
.pure-g-r {
    display: flex;
}
```

Further information: http://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/

Here a example using your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f3YNe/12/

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It works great in Firefox, but now Chrome is the problem. Using flex makes the `pure-u-1-3` stack upon each other in Chrome 32.0.1700.76m

Answer (score 2):

This has been fixed and accepted as a fix as part of pure's v0.6.0 milestone.
The fix can be seen on Github here: https://github.com/yahoo/pure/pull/351/files.

If you're using pure prior to 0.6.0 coming out adding

```
.pure-g-r {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
```

to your css should make things play nice in your layout.